# c# reflection finding overloaded method wr to inheritance

Tags: c#, reflection

I am trying to find via reflection the most appropriate method to invoke, when i have a type to pass to that method.

The edge case that is worrying me is overloading with same number of parameters, like so:

```
class UserClass {}
class UserClassB : UserClass {}

class SomeClass {
   void method(object x);
   void method(UserClass x);
}
```

in runtime i am interested in invoking `method`, while the type i have in hand is `UserClassB`.

The most appropriate would be `method(UserClass)`.

The problem is that when using `typeof(SomeClass).GetMethod("method", new Type[] { typeof(UserClass2) }));`  it will return a null, cause i think it searched based on  exact match for the passed types.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the binding flags.
use overload that you can pass the following flags:
BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic

you're getting null because the GetMethod will look for public method unless you specify you want non public methods too.

```
var method = typeof(SomeClass).GetMethod("method", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, new[] { typeof(UserClass) },null);
```

Comment: you are right :) in fact, i need it anyway only for public... but i tested it incorrectly. thanks!